# Power automate, copying date column from online excel to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, date-time

I want to copy date column from an online excel file to a SharePoint list column.

My flow does not update with the date column, it is returning blanks.

Does there need to be formatting to my SharePoint list column?

[image]

When I run my flow - these values are not copying over to my SharePoint list.

updated screenshot, Start is my date column:

[image]

Comment: Can you also paste your flow screenshot and are there any errors returned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formatDateTime` function to convert date in proper format before adding it to SharePoint list.

You have to use the expression in below format:

```
formatDateTime('10/30/2023')
```

**OR**

```
formatDateTime('30-Oct-23')
```

**Example**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Update**:

If above solution is not working for you, try this:

Click on **Show advanced options** link on **List rows present in a table** action and use **ISO 8601** option for **DateTime Format** like:

[image]

Comment: What if the data is a field, would it be `formatDateTime(datefield)`?

Comment: You have to pass the date value you get from excel file inside `formatDateTime` function using **Dynamic Content** pane.

Comment: shoukd this be done in compose or the actual create item? updating screenshots..

Comment: It is your choice. You can do it directly in create item action as well where you are passing excel value to list column.

Comment: full error `Error details: Input parameter 'item/field_4' is required to be of type 'String/date'. The runtime value '"formatDateTime()"' to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'String/date'.`

Comment: Can you try using compose as given in my answer once? Also, date in excel file is empty for any rows?

Comment: Refer my answer given here for detailed steps to add compose action output: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307040/power-automate-how-to-use-output-of-compose-to-create-item/307043#307043

Comment: Try another solution in above updated answer. Let me know if it works for you.