# Power Automate - How to use output of compose to create item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I am trying to use the output and conversion of my compose 2 into the create items. How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

no outputs option -

[image]

full flow -

[image]

`items('Apply_to_each')?[concat('Period Planned ','/',' Revised Date')]`

`addDays('1899-12-30',int(outputs('Compose')),'dd-MM-yyyy')`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to use output of compose action inside inputs to create item action:

1. Go to create item action and click inside the textbox against your targeted column where you want to use the output of compose action
2. It should open dynamic content pane automatically. If not opened, select **Add dynamic content** option:

   [image]
3. Search for **Outputs** from **Dynamic content** pane and select output from your **Compose 2** action:

   [image]
4. After adding compose action outputs, flow action should look like:

   [image]
5. Save your Power automate flow and run it.

Comment: I do not see this outputs as an option in dynamic content

Comment: If you have used Compose action before create item action, you should see it in the dynamic content section.

Comment: does the compose not have to be in an apply to each?

Comment: It should be in apply to each loop (of excel "value" output), but it has be before "create item" action so that you can use it's output in create item action.

Comment: very weird, i do not get the outputs as an option :(

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your complete flow if possible?

Comment: okay ive updated it.

Comment: Why you are using second apply to each loop for same excel **value** output? Use create item action inside first apply to each only - at the bottom end after all compose actions. It should work for you.

Comment: thanks ganesh. It does work for some records, but I get an error `The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Create_item_2' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: Input parameter 'item/field_4' is required to be of type 'String/date'. The runtime value '"30-10-2023"' to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'String/date'.`  But this is a "Date" column in excel.

Comment: Try setting **ISO 8601** inside **List rows present in a table** action as mentioned in my answer at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307015/power-automate-copying-date-column-from-online-excel-to-sharepoint-list

Comment: Now my data comes in the first compose as `2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z` which causes an error `'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.` hmm..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145015/discussion-between-jonnyboi-and-ganesh-sanap).

Answer (score 0):

There should be something this for you to choose?

[image]

Comment: i do not see this option